# Efficient way of checking condition within a do while loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I am using a Do While loop but i have to test whether that condition is met half way through the loop so that if it is met it will skip that part. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

e.g. I currently have something like this:

```
do {
    method1;
    if (!condition) 
        method2;
} while (!condition);
```

EDIT: I apologise, i don't think i made it clear in the first place. The condition starts as being false, and at some point during the loop one of the methods will set the (global) "condition" to true at which point i want the loop to immediately end. I just think it's messy having to test the ending condition of the loop within it and was wondering if there was anything obvious i was missing.

Comment: what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I am assuming you want to leave the while loop `if !condition` even in the middle of the loop?

Comment: Yes that's what i would like to do, BUT from what i can see since the loop is so simple adding a "break;" to it will just make it more complex as i still have to test the condition twice.

Comment: So, the condition is met better to bypass the loop and go to the next cycle.

Comment: @brent You could just move the call to method2 outside of the loop. That way the condition is only tested once.

Comment: True, unfortunately i don't think i explained the situation properly in the first post. Both method 1 and 2 must be looped consecutively until the point that one of them has set the condition to true, so they both have to be in the loop.

Comment: @brent Unfortunately I don't think there is a clean way to do that in Java. The repeated `if` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide more info about methods. If you can return condition from method1/2, then try:

```
do {
    method1;
} while (!condition && !method2)
```

or if you pass by reference and method return always true:

```
while (method1 && !condition && method2 && !condition);
```

or:

```
while (!method1 && !method2);
```

**EDIT:** if:

```
public boolean method1/2 { ... logic ... ; condition = true; return condition;}
```

it's hardly depend on what you will do.

Comment: That looks like the best way of doing it. Since it doesn't look like there is any efficient ay of improving on what i had, i'll make the methods return a boolean and have something similiar to what you have in the third code segment. Thank you!

Comment: Method returning boolean will result in catastrophe as while loop will run forever if method returns wrong value. Just keep your code simple thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your are looking for is avoiding this additional test for efficiency because   "condition" is not met most of the time (1 out of many)... 
This optimization may be done by going deeper into what is really done in method1 and method2 (or on the data they are handling) and add a first "fake step" outside of the loop that will disable treatment of method2 only the first time. Would look like this:

```
prepare_for_loop_entering
do {
   method2
   method1;
} while (!condition);
```

Comment: Thank you, similiar way of solving it to how Vikdor proposed. As i mentioned there i actually did have similiar code at the start. The test of the condition within the loop is something that has to be done with each iteration though so it will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if `condition` is the same on all the places you refer to it than

```
do {
    method1;
    method2;
} while (!condition);
```

as in your while loop `condition` will always be false (`!condition` will be true) unless you set it to true in `method1;` than you can just `break;` as soon as you set it to true in `method1;`

Comment: So there is no alternative? The condition could be set to true during the loop at anytime, in method 1 or 2. I could use a break; but due to the simplicity of the loop it's actually almost the same, if not better, the way i have it. But it just looks messy, i posted on here wondering if there is a better way - but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I don't think there is. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about the code below:

```
if(condition)
break;
```

Comment: That's a possibility but it will just end up adding a line of code if i understand correctly?

Comment: If the code is something where there is only one condition in picture then it `method2` should be outside of loop. And yes extra code will not cost you anything.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
 while (!condition) {
   method1;
if(!condition)
   method2;
}
```

Comment: what if he sets `condition` to true in `method1`? `method2` will still be accessed

Comment: The idea is something in the first method or second method will, eventually, at some time in the loop set the condition to true. I don't want to execute the second method if the first method has set it to true, but the two methods must be looped until that occurs.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. Whether i use a while, or do while loop in this situation does not matter too much as the condition will always be false at the start. The code still repeats the "!condition" part of the code which i think is a little bit messy, it seems like thats an unavoidable problem howver. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
method1;
while (!condition) {
   method2;
   method1;
}
```

Comment: That was similiar to how i was originally doing it, but if method2 sets the condition to true then the program will not function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the most generic form of a loop:

```
while (true)
{
    method1;
    if (!condition) break; 
    method2;
}
```

**Further explanation**

A while loop with a condition "condition" is exactly like:

```
while (true)
{
    if (condition) break;
    method1;
    method2;
}
```

And a do-while is exactly like:

```
while (true)
{
    method1;
    method2;
    if (condition) break;
}
```

We want neither of those, hence the code above.